# How come ADB can't access files without enabling USB debugging, but the Windows Explorer can?

Tags: windows, usb, android, adb

I've tried backing up my Android (Note 8) device using ADB. I've noticed that Developer Mode > USB Debugging must be enabled in order to even communicate with the device. However, it seems that transferring files through the Windows Explorer works without any need for any special permissions other than enabling file transfer in the device.
So my question is, is it possible to use software to backup the device without needing to enable developer mode and USB debugging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows uses by default the MTP protocol for accessing your phone. ADB uses the ADB protocol. Hence at a first glance both protocols may look identical but they work totally different.

The MTP protocol is by default enabled (the phone may ask you when you connect to a PC via USB).

The ADB protocol is mainly for developers and it allows you not only to upload/download file, it also allows you to install apps, run and debug self-developed apps, and change certain system settings, start apps, and a lot more.

The MTP protocol only allows you to access the internal storage and an external sd-card (if present), nothing more. Just upload and download files to these sections. hence the possibility to perform actions that harm your phone is very low.

On the other hand via adb there are various possibilities to harm your device or the privacy of your data, therefore the access is disabled by default.